# How to achieve a mirror copy in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, copy

I want to make two directories synchronized. I know there is a `robocopy /MIR` command in Windows that can achieve this.  Ex:

```
robocopy D:\test1 E:\Backup /MIR
```

When there is a file updated or deleted, the backup directory can keep synchronization.

I have tried in Linux through the `rsync` command like this:

```
rsync -a /usr/test /usr/backup
```

but when I delete a file under `/usr/test` and then run this command, the deleted file still exists in `/backup/test` — the two directories can't keep asynchronization.  So, how can I achieve the synchronization of two directories in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` has a `--delete` option which does what was asked:

```
 --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
```

It has a lot of related options.

Further reading:

- [rsync(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)
- [Commonly Used rsync Arguments](http://www.evbackup.com/support-commonly-used-rsync-arguments/)

Comment: This one has a huge gotcha.  Yes, I agree it is the closest, and I upvoted your answer and am glad to see it is accepted.  HOWEVER, if you add more exclusions to the rsync command, it will not delete the newly-excluded files.  And I have yet to find a way to reset the files list.  The only way I know to get rid of those exclusions is to erase the entire backup and then run it again from scratch.